# How dried up detergent water led to precipitation of snowflake like shapes?

Tags: crystal-structure, precipitation

I forgot to drain the water off the bucket (after cleaning stain from a piece of clothing with detergent) and left it for few days. After few days when I needed it back, I found these glittery very small snowflake like shapes at the bottom. Pardon if it's very basic thing, I haven't studied chemistry after school. Thanks for the help.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many water soluble molecules in soap. I believe that as the water evaporated, the concentration of these molecules became great enough for them to start crystallizing. This process is used in chemistry as a means of purification and is known as recrystallization.

Are you considering the X type shape of the crystals to be snowflake like? I am not quite sure why they all seem to have similar geometries, I want to guess that they are crystals of citric acid.

Comment: Yes X ones, But why X shapes?